# How can I implement CoroutineWorker using a third-party library that uses callbacks?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to implement a CoroutineWorker to do some background work in an Android app. The third-party library I'm using uses callbacks like onConnected, onChanged, etc. How can I use this library inside a CoroutineWorker?

This is what I have so far

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    return try {
        val appContext = applicationContext
        var mReporter: StepCountReporter?

        val mStepCountObserver = object : StepCountReporter.StepCountObserver {
            override fun onChanged(count: Int) {
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Step reported : $count")
                // This is where the work is completed
            }
        }

        val mConnectionListener = object : HealthDataStore.ConnectionListener {

            override fun onConnected() {
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is connected.")
                mReporter = StepCountReporter(mStore!!)
                if (isPermissionAcquired) {
                    mReporter!!.start(mStepCountObserver)
                } else {
                    Log.e(APP_TAG, "permissions not acquired")
                }
            }

            override fun onConnectionFailed(error: HealthConnectionErrorResult) {
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is not available.")
            }

            override fun onDisconnected() {
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is disconnected.")
            }
        }
        mStore = HealthDataStore(appContext, mConnectionListener)
        mStore!!.connectService()
        // wait for mStepCountObserver.onChanged to be called
    } catch (error: Throwable) {
        Result.failure()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to finish the coroutine inside mStepCountObserver.onChanged, but it looks like I'm supposed to call `Result.success` at the end of the function.

Comment: Try `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine`: https://jacquessmuts.github.io/post/callback_hell/ Here is where somebody is using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to give OkHttp a `suspend` variant: https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-okhttp/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/ru/gildor/coroutines/okhttp/CallAwait.kt

Comment: Apart from what @CommonsWare said you can refer Roman's talk https://youtu.be/YrrUCSi72E8?t=829 which shows how to integrate Callback styled libraries in Kotlin Coroutines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **suspendCoroutine** function, which helps to connect coroutines with  Callbacks.

'suspendCoroutine' suspends the coroutine which it is called from and only resumes that coroutine when 'resume()' or 'resumeWithException()' is called.

---

In your case,

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            val outputCount = suspendCoroutine<Int> {
                val appContext = applicationContext
                var mReporter: StepCountReporter?

                val mStepCountObserver = object : StepCountReporter.StepCountObserver {
                    override fun onChanged(count: Int) {
                        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Step reported : $count")
                        // This is where the work is completed
                        it.resume(Result.success(count))
                    }
                }

                val mConnectionListener = object : HealthDataStore.ConnectionListener {

                    override fun onConnected() {
                        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is connected.")
                        mReporter = StepCountReporter(mStore!!)
                        if (isPermissionAcquired) {
                            mReporter!!.start(mStepCountObserver)
                        } else {
                            Log.e(APP_TAG, "permissions not acquired")
                            it.resumeWithException(Exception("permissions not acquired"))
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onConnectionFailed(error: HealthConnectionErrorResult) {
                        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is not available.")
                        it.resumeWithException(Exception("Health data service is not available."))
                    }

                    override fun onDisconnected() {
                        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is disconnected.")
                        it.resumeWithException(Exception("Health data service is disconnected."))
                    }
                }
                mStore = HealthDataStore(appContext, mConnectionListener)
                mStore!!.connectService()
                // wait for mStepCountObserver.onChanged to be called

            }

            Result.success()
        } catch (error: Throwable) {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }
```